# How to open php socket connection and request/maintain data from client

Tags: php, sockets

So I want to make a `daemon.php` file which can open a port on a give ip address and request data from `client.php` and with the browser to listen/read to earlier pipe (Would that be a problem for the security or not?).
I fount this [funphp tutorial](http://www.funphp.com/?p=33) which seems to be good but is more like a cronjob, I found also function [stream-socket-server](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.stream-socket-server.php) but can handle only one request and then shuts down, and I really don't know where exactly to put listener.

Comment: That's not the way php is supposed to be working. PHP is really about request/response. There is no natural support for scripts running longer than a single request.

Comment: @pintxo No, there is a way, the PHP Built--In Server : it is created especially to help developers and for testing purposes only...

Comment: but are so many function there like flush for example who is able to respond to server and also to maintain the connection open

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP Built-In Server

Add **PHP** to your **PATH** environment variable

Start your server on a given port, ex: `php -S localhost:8000` **OR**

Start with a **router** script, ex: `php -S localhost:8000` rt.php

Now, just open your browser and type; `localhost:8000`

Comment: @JohniDevo, sorry i don't understand your question

Comment: The `-S` from the `php -S localhost:8000 rt.php` is also a scipt and contains what i write earlier in my question

Comment: The `-S` it is an option that means 'START' i think, in your case you have to do like this : `php -S localhost:8000 daemon.php`